# React native - button wont style

Tags: react-native, styled-components

#### I have a styled button,created with styled-components, but the styles I created are not applying to it. Am I doing something wrong?

```
    const ButtonStyled = styled.Button`
      margin-top:10px;
    `;
```

```
    return (
        <ButtonStyled
            title={`Calcular ${pct}%`}
            onPress={calc}
        />
    )
```

Comment: reactnative.dev/docs/button A basic button component that should render nicely on any platform. Supports a minimal level of customization. If this button doesn't look right for your app, you can build your own button using TouchableOpacity.

Answer (score 1):

A month ago i had the same problem...

I recommend to change the Button styled for TouchableOpacity.

The TouchableOpacity style is more like a div then a button

The title attribute will be replaced for a Text component of React-Native itself

So the style code will be:

```
const ButtonStyled = styled.TouchableOpacity`
  margin-top:10px;
`;
```

And the JSX code:

```
<ButtonStyled>
   <Text>What ever you want</Text>

</ButtonStyled>
```